# Org tangle source blocks to a file with byte-order-mark (BOM) from org mode

Tags: org-mode, character-encoding, unicode, tangle

Because Firefox doesn't load local files with UTF8 characters like ', …, ' in the HTML or the CSS correctly, since it does not receive a `<meta charset="utf8" />` header, I need to tangle files with a Byte-Order-Mark.

I knew that my needed BOM was `\xef\xbb\xbf` or `\357\273\277`.

My first try was just prepending this block:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC fundamental
\357\273\277
#+END_SRC
That line in emacs is really 3 characters, not 12 as rendered here
```

When I tangle with `C-c -v -t`, I get a "Select coding system" prompt twice, where I have to choose `utf-8-with-signature' both times.

That puts the BOM at the front of the file, but also another time at the end. Then I `find-file-literally` the tangle result file, to remove the trailing one manually. And I have a "superfluous" Source Block...

The other work-around, which I have been using since then: Using `sed` externally:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :tangle no
sed -i  '1s/^\(\xef\xbb\xbf\)\?/\xef\xbb\xbf/' Empty.org.htm
#+END_SRC
```

and then I just tangle that chapter, and execute the shell block afterwards. That became muscle memory and thus fast (enough). But also another source block needed in the doc.

I always wondered about the correct™ way to do this. From my reading I suspect, there is a variable I can set somewhere as a header var, or in a property drawer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the correct variable to set while on an unrelated research dig:

`coding` can be set in a `Local Variables` block like so:

```
 # Local Variables:
 # mode: org
 # coding: utf-8-with-signature
 # End:
```

Note: there is a leading space in each line of the preceding source block.

This setting then gets inherited by the tangled files.